# line doesn't execute in .bash_profile and .bashrc on my Mac OSX Snow Leopard

Tags: unix, osx-snow-leopard, rvm

I just installed Ruby Version Manager (RVM) which is working fine but it asked me to put the following line in my /.bash_profile and ~/.bashrc files:

```
if [[ -s /Users/tammam56/.rvm/scripts/rvm ]] ; then source /Users/tammam56/.rvm/scripts/rvm ; fi
```

looking at the content I see the following:

```
tammam56$ cat /.bash_profile
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
if [[ -s /Users/tammam56/.rvm/scripts/rvm ]] ; then source /Users/tammam56/.rvm/scripts/rvm ; fi

tammam56$ cat ~/.bashrc 
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export MANPATH=/usr/local/man:$MANPATH
if [[ -s /Users/tammam56/.rvm/scripts/rvm ]] ; then source /Users/tammam56/.rvm/scripts/rvm ; fi
```

However when I start new Terminal window it doesn't execute the command I know this as I set my default Ruby verion to 1.9 and if I execute the line manually I get to the correct version:

```
tammam56$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 72) [universal-darwin10.0]
Macintosh-37:~ tammam56$ if [[ -s /Users/tammam56/.rvm/scripts/rvm ]] ; then source /Users/tammam56/.rvm/scripts/rvm ; fi
Macintosh-37:~ tammam56$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.1p378 (2010-01-10 revision 26273) [i386-darwin10.2.0]
```

Any ideas how I can fix that?

Thanks,

Tam

Comment: Check that bash is in fact your login shell.  If you created your account prior to 10.3 the default was tcsh but it can be changed using chsh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a ~/.profile try adding the following line to it.

if [[ -s /Users/tammam56/.rvm/scripts/rvm ]] ; then source /Users/tammam56/.rvm/scripts/rvm ; fi

Answer (score 1):

Have you confirmed that other commands in .bashrc and/or .bash_profile get updated properly?

Next you should confirm whether Terminal is starting the shell as a login shell or not (see under Preferences -> Startup).

From the bash man page:

> When  bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-inter-
>          active shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes  com-
>          mands  from  the file /etc/profile, if that file exists.  After reading
>          that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile,
>          in  that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that
>          exists and is readable.  The --noprofile option may be  used  when  the
>          shell is started to inhibit this behavior.
>
> When an interactive shell that is not a login shell  is  started,  bash
>          reads  and executes commands from ~/.bashrc, if that file exists.  This
>          may be inhibited by using the --norc option.  The --rcfile file  option
>          will  force  bash  to  read  and  execute commands from file instead of
>          ~/.bashrc.

Comment: Thanks Ether. Looking are preferences > Startup : Shells open with Default login shell (/usr/bin/login). What do you mean by "Have you confirmed that other commands in .bashrc and/or .bash_profile get updated properly?"

Comment: @Tam: try putting `echo "running .bashrc"` in your .bashrc, and `echo "running .bash_profile"` in your .bash_profile -- which of these files are being executed by a new Terminal?

Comment: Thanks Ether. I tried that but I didn't get any display! I guess my bash doesn't execute neither of these files!! I tried @UnderpantsGnome suggestion and it worked! I also added echo "executing .profile" at the bottom of it and saw the output!

Answer (score 0):

I found that the easiest solution to this issue was to move all of the contents from my ~/.bashrc file (so my ~/.bashrc is now empty) to a new ~/.bash_profile file.  Now all Terminal.app tabs automatically run all lines included in ~/.bash_profile.  This also applies to iTerm.