# RVM shortcuts in bash_profile not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, bash

Having some problems with the RVM command line shortcuts - RVM seems to be installing correctly but can't access commands from the CLI. Here is my bash_profile file - anything obvious here?

```
>     [[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile
>     
>     [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a
> function*
>     source /Users/mycomputer/.rvm/scripts/rvm
>     source /Users/mycomputer/.rvm/scripts/rvm
>     ~
```

Comment: Why do you have duplicate?

Comment: Also, have you tried rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles

Comment: If you're on OSX, maybe see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309103/line-doesnt-execute-in-bash-profile-and-bashrc-on-my-mac-osx-snow-leopard).

Comment: > Also, have you tried rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles -- this worked